# Using jBPM single zip distribution, how do I upload a large jar with dependencies to Artifacts?

Tags: maven, wildfly, jbpm, undertow

I am using jbpm-server-7.33.0.Final-dist.zip I have a maven WorkItemHandler project that generates PDF files and as such. It has a built `jar-with-dependencies.jar` that is 52 mb.

I tried to upload the jar to the Business Central Artifacts, but I get

```
Caused by: io.undertow.server.RequestTooBigException: 
    UT000020: Connection terminated as request was larger than 10485760
```

I tried changing `10485760` to `90485760` in these files

```
domain/configuration/domain.xml
standalone/configuration/standalone-full-ha.xml
standalone/configuration/standalone_xml_history/standalone.last.xml
standalone/configuration/standalone_xml_history/standalone.boot.xml
standalone/configuration/standalone.xml
standalone/configuration/standalone-full.xml
```

But after those changes and restarting the server nothing changed.

I don't know how to decrease my dependencies, I only have org.jbpm.jbpm-test and org.apache.pdfbox.pdfbox. Without dependencies my jar is only ~5K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase max-post size in undertow subsystem in the configuration file, like as

```
<server name="default-server">
    <http-listener name="default" max-post-size="1000" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https"/>
```

Also you should not add dpendency of org.jbpm:jbpm-test artifact on project/jar which you are going to deploy somewhere else. You should use this artifact only for writing junit tests.

Comment: Do you have any clue which configuration file this is? I have the same section in at least 3 files; standalone.xml, standalone-full.xml, domain.xml

Comment: You need to findout which configuration file you are using to start server intance. With default configuration server will use standalone.xml file if you are using standalone mode